# How to fix the test and train set in svm using matlab?

Tags: matlab, svm

I am new to matlab. I want to know how to fixed the train and test set in **`svm`** code because I had **[find a code](http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring11/group04/application_Kan.pdf)**, the code randomly selects the test and train set. my database is **`YMU`** database, how should I fix the train and test set using **`svm`** code. because I use the `crossvalind` to randomly select the train and test set. which variable should I change with the crossvalind?

```
%load YMU database
%NMC is non-makeup , MC is makeup
%testingset = non-makeup, trainingset is makeup
load TestingSetNMC.mat
load TrainingSetMC.mat
load gnd_Test.mat
load gnd_Train.mat

data1 = TrainingSet;
data2 = TestingSet;
groups1 = ismember(gnd_Train,'data1');
groups2 = ismember(gnd_Test,'data2');
%crossvalind is random choose
[train] = crossvalind('holdOut',groups1);
[test] = crossvalind('holdOut',groups2);
cp = classperf(groups1);
svmStruct = svmtrain(data1(train,:),groups1(train),'showplot',true);
classes = svmclassify(svmStruct,data2(test,:),'showplot',true);
classperf(cp,classes,test);
cp.CorrectRate
```

Answer (score 0):

With (most) matlab functions that generate pseudo-random output you can control that output by explicitly specifying a random number generator's seed and method.

In your case, place the following line anywhere before you call `crossvalind`:

```
rng(1, 'twister');
```

This sets the seed to 1 and the method to Mersenne Twister. In the documentation for `rng` you will find a more detailed explanation about controlling pseudo-random output.